# How to connect a PIC32MK 100-pin Motor Control Plug-In Module (PIM) for programming

Tags: pic, mplabx, mplab, pickit

I recently got a PIC32MK 100-pin Motor Control Plug-In Module (PIM) I have been trying to prgram it but I have been running into the following error:

```
Target voltage detected
Unable to connect to the target device.
Failed to get Device ID
```

**I am currently connecting my 3.3V source to pins:**

PIN 2 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER) as VDD (connected to + side of the source)

PIN 15 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER as VSS (connected to the - side of the source)

**I am conneceting the pickit 3 to the following:**

Pickit Pin 1 (the one with the arrow): PIN 13 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER) as MCLR

Pickit Pin 2: PIN 16 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER) as VDD

Pickit Pin 3: Pin 36 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER) as VSS

Pickit Pin 4: Pin 27 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER) as PGD

Pickit Pin 5: Pin 26 (IN THE MICROCONTROLLER) as PGC

Pickit Pin 6: Not connected

Here is the source of where I am getting the values: (Note I have the 100 pin so I am using the diagram in page 5) http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32MK_GP_MC_Familly_Datasheet_60001402G.pdf

the code I am attempting to upload to the Pic is the following:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1irJj6f744SAhsiNDJO9QxzUNfxEsFJPe file called PWM-centered-interrupt...

Am I connecting to the wrong pins? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check all items described in chapter 2 of the datasheet (decoupling capacitors, pullup in MCLR, no components influencing PGECx/PGEDx, etc)

Comment: I did! recreated the MCLR configuration but still nothing

Comment: You probably didn't! Carefully check **all** items again, also the very first bullet (which may cause your issue): *The following is a list of pin names, which must always be connected:
**All VDD and VSS pins** (see 2.2 “Decoupling Capacitors”)* You only connected pin 2 and 15 and maybe pins 16&36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully check all items of chapter 2, also the very first bullet (which may cause your issue)

> The following is a list of pin names, which must always be connected:
>   - **All** VDD and VSS pins (see 2.2 “Decoupling Capacitors”)

You write you only connected pin 2 and 15. The connection to pins 16&36 you write about only count when you turned on the option the PicKIT is powering the device (which I'd advise against in this case).

Do connect **all** power pins to the power source and provide a decoupling capacitor as close as possible **to each** Vdd/Vss pair.